# Google Cast CastRemoteDisplayLocalService Audio Lag

Tags: android, audio, google-cast

I am working with CastRemoteDisplayLocalService and CastPresentation to do remote display in my app. The app can be pretty graphics heavy at times but when a user is playing audio the cast can become very laggy. This ruins the experience of the graphics cast and audio playing. Even if I turn the graphics down to almost nothing the Audio still creates lag. Essentially I am wondering how to prevent audio from streaming along with the Remote Display and keep it playing on the phone or send it in a way that's more stable. I have searched but can't find much about the audio sent with Remote Display and can't understand why it would be forced to play if not coming from specifically my app.

Comment: Could you please contact the Google Cast team at this link so we can help you debug the issue: https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1
Please refer to this issue in the form.

Comment: @LeonNicholls That was my first step and the response to my email told me to join and ask the Stackoverflow community.

Comment: Please reach out again. We need to debug this with you.